# svg compatibility problems with fonts

Tags: svg, inkscape

my friend created a svg graphics with some text on windows in inkscape and sent it to me. I opened it in inkscape on linux and text was "bigger" same font, same size but on my system it was bigger.

We tried Sans and Serif fonts but both are not working same on different systems. Why?

I would like to include svg into pdf, so my question is: Would will be the pdf looks same everywhere or it can be different on every pc?

I want to create svg with php and then transform it into pdf on my web server...

Thanks

Comment: Are you explicitly setting a font size?  If not, the SVG viewer will use a default font size, which might be different in different viewers (including different versions of Inkscape).

Comment: yup, I have <text><tspan>Text</tspan></text> and text element has style with font-size:22.28629112px;

Comment: One more question: is the size of the SVG as a whole (width and height attributes for the `<svg>` element) defined in px or as numbers without units?  If it is defined in inches/centimeters, the different viewers could be using different scaling factors, which could affect the scale of the text relative to the graphics.

Comment: It is a number without units...

Comment: Then I'm stumped.  Can you try creating a super-simple example that shows the effect you're talking about, then open the SVG file in a text editor and copy and past the code into the question?

Comment: I have the same issue, Wonder if this ever got solved?